# Programatically export XML results from JUnit tests?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am running JUnit tests in Eclipse. At the end I would like to export the results in an XML file. This can be done manually using the export feature in the JUnit view.

Is it possible to automatically do this export from my Java code at the end of the test? ANT is not an option!

Comment: How is Ant not an option?

Comment: I need to generate the JUNIT View to visualize them for People watching. Running Ant results in me not having that view.